# error = Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Garbage at end."

Tags: ios, json, paytm

Im Using PayTm SDK in my app. Im getting above error while setting up.

```
  mc.checksumGenerationURL = @"My URL";
  mc.checksumValidationURL = @"My URL ";
```

// Here Im passing my server Urls
    //Step 3: Create the order with whatever params you want to add. But make sure that you include the merchant mandatory params

```
    NSMutableDictionary *orderDict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
//Merchant configuration in the order object


orderDict[@"MID"] = @""; //Passes my Id

orderDict[@"CHANNEL_ID"] = @"WAP";
orderDict[@"INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID"] = @"Retail";
orderDict[@"WEBSITE"] = @""; Passed my website



//Order configuration in the order object
orderDict[@"CUST_ID"] = @"123456";
orderDict[@"ORDER_ID"] = [ViewController generateOrderIDWithPrefix:@""];
orderDict[@"TXN_AMOUNT"] = @"1";

orderDict[@"REQUEST_TYPE"] = @"DEFAULT";



PGOrder *order = [PGOrder orderWithParams:orderDict];

//Step 4: Choose the PG server. In your production build dont call selectServerDialog. Just create a instance of the
//PGTransactionViewController and set the serverType to eServerTypeProduction

     PGTransactionViewController *txnController = [[PGTransactionViewController alloc] initTransactionForOrder:order];
         txnController.serverType =eServerTypeStaging ;

        //  txnController.loggingEnabled = YES;
          // txnController.sendAllChecksumResponseParamsToPG = YES;
         txnController.merchant = mc;
         txnController.delegate = self;
         [self showController:txnController];
```

Please help me..
Thank you...

Comment: Hello, same problem is arrive if you solve this please give me answer...Thanx

Comment: @sohil Please check my answer, It will help you.

Answer (score 1):

The CheckSum generation URL Should only contain three parameters.The .aspx page should not contain form code. Please check the screen shot below. [image]

In IOS at the time of  generate check sum only high lighted value should be print but it is printing form also.

which is wrong that's why it is showing garbage at the end.

Comment: What if I am using default paytm url ? How do I do it? Also can you share what version of paytm SDK are you using?

Comment: Im using 2.12.2 version.Im not png my using my server url not sure about default paytm url